# Angular velocity in terms of quaternions

Tags: kinematics, theory

Im reading *Theory of Applied Robotics, 2nd edition* by Jazar, specifically section 7.1, example 207 on page 390. The author is trying to express angular velocity by unit quaternions. Starting from quaternion representation of rotation
\begin{equation}
{}^G \mathbf r = e(t) {}^B \mathbf r e^*(t) \tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $e$ is unit quaternion and $e^*$ is its inverse. Using product rule for derivative and $(1)$ we get
\begin{align}
{}^G \dot{\mathbf r} &= \dot e {}^B \mathbf r e^* + e {}^B\mathbf r \dot{e}^*\\
&= \dot e e^* {}^G \mathbf r + {}^G \mathbf r e\dot{e}^*\\
&= 2\dot e e^* {}^G \mathbf r
\end{align}

Author states that 3rd equality comes from orthogonality property of unit quaternion $ee^* = 1$ which produces, using product rule
\begin{equation}
\dot e e^* + e \dot{e}^* = 0
\end{equation}
Using this we should get
\begin{align}
{}^G \dot{\mathbf r} &= \dot e {}^B \mathbf r e^* + e {}^B\mathbf r \dot{e}^*\\
&= \dot e e^* {}^G \mathbf r + {}^G \mathbf r e\dot{e}^*\\
&= \dot e e^* {}^G \mathbf r - {}^G \mathbf r \dot e e^*\\
\end{align}
so apparently to get $2\dot e e^* {}^G \mathbf r$ in the end it should be that
\begin{equation}
- {}^G \mathbf r \dot e e^* = \dot e e^* {}^G \mathbf r \tag{2}
\end{equation} 
I'm looking for an answer that explains how do we derive $(2)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A definition of the [cross product for quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Quaternions_and_the_geometry_of_R3) is $$p \times q = \frac{1}{2}(pq - qp)$$

We also have the identity (3.167) in Jazar $$pq = -p \cdot q + p \times q$$

Apparently the vectors $ \dot{e}\overset{\ast}{e} $ and ${}^Gr$ are orthogonal, so their dot product is zero and we have: $$\dot{e} \overset{\ast}{e}{}^Gr = \dot{e} \overset{\ast}{e} \times {}^Gr = \frac{1}{2}(\dot{e}\overset{\ast}{e}{}^Gr - {}^Gr \dot{e}\overset{\ast}{e})$$ which can be rewritten as $$ 2\dot{e}\overset{\ast}{e}{}^Gr =  \dot{e}\overset{\ast}{e}{}^Gr - {}^Gr\dot{e}\overset{\ast}{e}$$ and thus $\dot{e}\overset{\ast}{e}{}^Gr = - {}^Gr\dot{e}\overset{\ast}{e}$.

(footnote: I found [this PDF](https://www.euclideanspace.com/physics/kinematics/angularvelocity/QuaternionDifferentiation2.pdf) somewhat helpful.)

Answer (score 0):

This is given:
\begin{align}
{}^G \dot{\mathbf r} &= 2\dot e e^* {}^G \mathbf r
\end{align}

And also:

\begin{align}
{}^G \dot{\mathbf r} &= \dot e e^* {}^G \mathbf r - {}^G \mathbf r \dot e e^*\\
\end{align}
Equating both one has:
\begin{align}
2\dot e e^* {}^G \mathbf r &= \dot e e^* {}^G \mathbf r - {}^G \mathbf r \dot e e^*\\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\dot e e^* {}^G \mathbf r &= - {}^G \mathbf r \dot e e^*\\
\end{align}
The last equation is $(2)$.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but ${}^G \dot{\mathbf r} = 2\dot e e^* {}^G \mathbf r$ is not given, maybe you misunderstood me. This is the end result we are trying to get. This would be some kind of circular reasoning so it doesn't really work.